# websocket and cloudmqtt, code example not working

Tags: websocket, mqtt, paho

is it possible to work with websockets and [cloudmqtt](http://www.cloudmqtt.com)?
I have following code but nothing is working.
First I use the mqttw31.js from Paho and in my host file I define all the connection details.

```js
src="js/mqttws31.js" type="text/javascript">
src="js/host.js" type="text/javascript">                                                                        
var mqtt;
var reconnectTimeout = 2000;
function MQTTconnect() {
mqtt = new Paho.MQTT.Client(
                            host,
                            port,
                            "web_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100,
                            10));
var options = {
     timeout: 3,
     useSSL: useTLS,
     cleanSession: cleansession,
     onSuccess: onConnect,
     onFailure: function (message) {
       $('#status').val("Connection failed: " + message.errorMessage + "Retrying");
       setTimeout(MQTTconnect, reconnectTimeout);
     }
};
mqtt.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
mqtt.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;
if (username != null) {
    options.userName = username;
    options.password = password;
}
console.log("Host="+ host + ", port=" + port + " TLS = " + useTLS + " username=" + username + " password=" + password);
mqtt.connect(options);
}
function onConnect() {
    $('#status').val('Connected to ' + host + ':' + port);
    // Connection succeeded; subscribe to our topic
    mqtt.subscribe(topic, {qos: 0});
    $('#topic').val(topic);
    mqtt.publish("/arduino/commando/", "test Intel");
}
function onConnectionLost(response) {
    setTimeout(MQTTconnect, reconnectTimeout);
    $('#status').val("connection lost: " + responseObject.errorMessage + ". Reconnecting");
};
function onMessageArrived(message) {
    var topic = message.destinationName;
    var payload = message.payloadString;
    $('#ws').prepend('<li>' + topic + ' = ' + payload + '</li>');
};
$(document).ready(function() {
MQTTconnect();
});
```

```html
<header>
<h2>MQTT Test</h2>
</header>
<div>
Subscribed to <input type='text' id='topic' disabled />
Status: <input type='text' id='status' size="80" disabled />
<ul id='ws' style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;"></ul>
</div>
```

In the host file:

```
host = 'm20.cloudmqtt.com'; // hostname or IP address
port = 13365;
topic = '/arduino/status/';     // topic to subscribe to
useTLS = false;
username = "test";
password = "test";
cleansession = true;
```

Comment: What results are you seeing, and what's wrong with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use port 33365 and set useTLS to true.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the cloudmqtt.com doc doesn't mention websockets anywhere.

Assuming they are running Mosquitto 1.4, this does not use the same port for native MQTT and MQTT over websockets so if they are only providing you with 1 port number then it really isn't going to work.

Comment: Are there any other platforms you can recommend?

Comment: I'm not aware of any cloud base MQTT solutions offering WebSockets at the moment

Comment: CloudMQTT does now support Websockets, on the base port + 20 000 (ie. in this example 33365), and only over TLS (WSS)